# Displaying specific patches in NetLogo from Excel data

Tags: csv, coordinates, netlogo, patch

The purpose of this model is to display patches that were occupied by wolf-agents and show where the wolves made successful kills (of prey agents). The data is provided by a CSV file which lists all patch coordinates that had wolf-visitation at some point and if there was a successful kill. The format of the CSV file is: tick #, patch-id (pxcor pycor), wolf-pack-id, and kill-count. At the moment, I just want the patches that have pxcor pycor = patch-id to have an "ACTIVE" attribute so I can easily differentiate which patches were visited by wolves and which patches were not visited by wolf agents.

```
globals [
  grass-patches                 ;; NLCD classifications
  forest-patches
  urban-patches
  agriculture-patches
  water-patches
  barren-patches
  vegetation-dataset           ;; DEM data layers
  elevation-dataset
  slope-dataset
  map-data                     ;;CSV data from wolf model-- wolf dispersal and kmarker location
  ]

patches-own [
  NLCDtype          ;; The grouping/classifications of the different NLCD veg-types--these correspond to the global patch types
  veg-type          ;; NLCD gridcodes for teh vegetation data
  veg-amount        ;; Resources/biomass available for the prey to consume
  elevation         ;; DEM
  slope             ;; DEM
  countdown         ;; How the vegetation "grow" and die through the model time
  hash-id           ;; The UNIQUE ID (xy coordinates) for each patch
    
  wolf-occupation   ;; How to tell if a wolf agent has been in the patch: ACTIVE shows occupation, INACTIVE has no wolf occupation
]
```

So far, I have successfully loaded the data into my .nlogo project by having the .CSV read line by line:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-gis
  load-csv-data
  ask patches [ set hash-id (word pxcor " " pycor)]   
end

to load-csv-data
 ifelse ( file-exists? "ph-memory_TEST.csv" )
 [
   file-open "Ph-memory_TEST.csv"
    while [ not file-at-end? ]
    [set map-data csv:from-row file-read-line]
    user-message "File loading complete!"
    ]
  [user-message "There is an error reading the CSV data"]

end
```

The CSV file format is:[image: CSV]

I tried to implement a "while" loop by having this command:

```
to load-wolf-data
  cp
  ifelse ( is-list? map-data )
  [foreach map-data [
    ask patches [while (pxcor pycor = position 1 map-data) [set wolf-occupation "ACTIVE"]
  ] ]]
    [user-message "You need to load the map data first!"]
end
```

NetLogo gives a syntax error with the current code, but I am hoping someone can help me implement this wolf-occupation status correctly. Or, if someone could help me understand how to correlate the CSV file's patch-id to the .nlogo pxcor pycor.

Comment: can you please show us some example csv data? You have listed the variable names but it's not clear whether there is a space or comma in the patch identifier for example.

Comment: @JenB Thank you for the advice. I have included the CSV format for clarification

Comment: It looks to me like your map-data load will only keep the final line. That is, each loop through the `while` replaces the variable map-data with the new line of data. Are you sure this contains the full dataset? After the import, print it out and check.